# How to get nth item from a TreeMap?

Tags: java, treemap, sortedmap

I have a `TreeMap<Date, Integer>` and I want to fetch the *n*th item from that map. What I came up with now is this:

```
((Integer)myTreeMap.values().toArray()[index]).intValue();
```

but this feels quite clunky, not to mention what is happening on the heap or with performance?

Is there a concise way to get the *n*th item from a `TreeMap`/`SortedMap` ?

Comment: Why not use a stream on the treemap-values and skip n-1 elements and get the first of the rest?

Comment: Unless you have a custom implementation, iterating is the only way to know which leaf node is the 'nth'.

Comment: The default TreeMap implementation does not support that. It uses an internal `java.util.TreeMap.Values` type to keep the values that does not add support for index-based access. Similarly for the key Set. They do make it easy though to get values for keys above/below thresholds, maybe you can try to use that instead of n-th value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit: an alternative is

```
final Optional<T> first =
        treeMap.values()
               .stream()
               .skip(index - 1)
               .findFirst();

if (first.isPresent()) {
    final T value = first.get();
}
```

What about

```
final List<T> values = new ArrayList<>(myTreeMap.values());
final T value = values.get(index);
```

`T` is just a generic type in place of your `Map` value type.
`index` is your *nth* element.

As pointed out, that's inefficient for large maps, as internally the `ArrayList` constructor the `toArray` method is called

```
public Object[] toArray() {
    // Estimate size of array; be prepared to see more or fewer elements
    Object[] r = new Object[size()];
    Iterator<E> it = iterator();
    for (int i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {
        if (! it.hasNext()) // fewer elements than expected
            return Arrays.copyOf(r, i);
        r[i] = it.next();
    }
    return it.hasNext() ? finishToArray(r, it) : r;
}
```

Comment: This is very inefficient if the map is large... you instantiate a full list of all values just to get a single value that could be really close to the "head".

Comment: @Renato the same is valid for the Stream version, using Collect.toList, I think.

Comment: Not at all. The stream version does not require collect over the full collection (it does not even require collect, that answer needs improvements).

Comment: @Renato Yeah, but you have to use findFirst after skipping. Using Collectors.toList you need the full list.

Answer (score 2):

We can try using a stream here.  In the snippet below, we create a sorted map with five entries.  Then, we create a stream, skipping the first 3 elements, and using `findFirst` to capture the first element.

```
Map<Integer, String> myTreeMap = new TreeMap<>();
myTreeMap.put(1, "one");
myTreeMap.put(2, "two");
myTreeMap.put(3, "three");
myTreeMap.put(4, "four");
myTreeMap.put(5, "five");
String fourth = myTreeMap.entrySet().stream()
   .skip(3)
   .map(map -> map.getValue()).findFirst().get();
System.out.println("fourth value in map is: " + fourth);
```

Comment: Why stream over the entryset when you could use the values and only need them?

Comment: Just do `treeMap.values().stream().skip(5).findFirst().orElse(-1)`

Comment: @mayamar the map probably internally maintains its data as `Entry`s; calling `values()` would force it to first fully resolve those to create that collection. So it depends on the implementation, but chances are higher that this is more efficient.

Comment: @daniu no, I checked, both calls "getFirstEntry()", and both use an Iterator starting from there

Answer (score 2):

You can use steam and skip n-1 elements and take the first as below:
`tmap.entrySet().stream().skip(n-1).findFirst();`. Details with data set examples:

```
TreeMap<Date, Integer> tmap = new TreeMap<Date, Integer>();
tmap.put(new Date(2014, 1, 1), 0);
tmap.put(new Date(2015, 1, 1), 1);
tmap.put(new Date(2016, 1, 1), 2);
tmap.put(new Date(2017, 1, 1), 3);
tmap.put(new Date(2018, 1,1 ), 4);

System.out.println(tmap);

// Let's find the nth elements i.e n = 3;
int n = 3;
System.out.println(" " + n + " elements: ");
System.out.println(tmap.entrySet().stream().skip(n-1).findFirst());
```

Output as follow:

```
{Sun Feb 01 00:00:00 IST 3914=0, Mon Feb 01 00:00:00 IST 3915=1, Tue Feb 01 00:00:00 IST 3916=2, Thu Feb 01 00:00:00 IST 3917=3, Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 IST 3918=4}
3 elements: 
Optional[Tue Feb 01 00:00:00 IST 3916=2]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way of getting the Nth key / value from a Map. and that is simply to add a counter.

```
int count = 1;
for (Map.Entry entry : Map.entrySet())
        {
            if (count == 1) //the Nth value
            {
                System.out.println(count + " "
                     + entry.getKey() + " "
                     + entry.getValue());
            }
            count++;
        }
```